# Display div element in forloop using querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm trying to display certain div elements in a forloop and would like javascript to identify the correct one. For example:

```
<div id="box">
  <div class="red-box"></div>
</div>
<div id="box">
  <div class="green-box"></div>
</div>
<div id="box">
  <div class="blue-box"></div>
</div>

const boxes = document.querySelectorAll("#box");
for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
  //if array is 0 display red box
  //If array is 1 display a green box
  //If array is 2 display a blue box
}
```

If I click the first div class box and want to display a red box but if I click the 3rd div class box it will display a blue box.

Comment: invalid HTML code => **id must be unique**

Comment: so addd click event listener and show the child....

Comment: @epascarello yeah that's what I want to do

Comment: @Yousaf I'll add what I was trying to do but I'm still figuring it out. Plus I'm doing it on Shopify theme code if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a class since Ids have to be unique. Add click event listener, show the child inside.

```js
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
  boxes[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    this.children[0].classList.toggle("active");
  });
}
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}

.box > div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
}

.box > div.active {
  display: block;
}

.red-box {
  background-color: red;  
}

.green-box {
  background-color: green;  
}

.blue-box {
  background-color: blue;  
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="red-box"></div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <div class="green-box"></div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <div class="blue-box"></div>
</div>
```

And without JavaScript

```css
.selector {
  display: none;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}

.box > div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
}

.selector:checked + .box > div {
  display: block;
}

.red-box {
  background-color: red;  
}

.green-box {
  background-color: green;  
}

.blue-box {
  background-color: blue;  
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="box1" class="selector">
<label for="box1" class="box">
  <div class="red-box"></div>
</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="box2" class="selector">
<label for="box2" class="box">
  <div class="green-box"></div>
</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="box3" class="selector">
<label for="box3" class="box">
  <div class="blue-box"></div>
</label>

<hr/>

<input type="radio" name="color" id="box1r" class="selector">
<label for="box1r" class="box">
  <div class="red-box"></div>
</label>
<input type="radio" name="color" id="box2r" class="selector">
<label for="box2r" class="box">
  <div class="green-box"></div>
</label>
<input type="radio" name="color" id="box3r" class="selector">
<label for="box3r" class="box">
  <div class="blue-box"></div>
</label>
```

Comment: Is there a way to change it from toggle to add. Then add a code function onclick that can remove the .active, but still allow the addEventListener to add the .active if necessary?

Answer (score 0):

1. id must be unique.
2. Don't use id unless you have to.
3. Get rid of unnecessary parents.
4. I use data attributes for colors because it's easier than using class.

```
<div class="box" data-color="red"></div>
<div class="box" data-color="blue"></div>
<div class="box" data-color="green"></div>
```

and javascript:

```
let boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
[...boxes].forEach(box => {
   box.addEventListener("click", () => {
     let color = event.target.dataset.color;
     // You have color name now.
     // Do whatever you want to do with it.
   })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can do something like this:**

```js
function fillDiv() 
{
        var div = document.getElementById('change');
    var selection = document.getElementById('bgcolor').value;
    var text = document.getElementById('message');
    
    switch (selection) 
    {
        case "1":
            div.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
            text.style.color = "lightblue";
            break;
        case "2":
            div.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
            text.style.color = "yellow";
            break;
        case "3":
            div.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
            text.style.color = "white";
            break;
    }
}
```

```css
h4.fill-div 
{
    display: block;
    padding:10px;
    width: 100%;
    color: Green;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

div.fill
{
  height:30px;
  width:100%; 
  position: absolute; 
  float:bottom; 
  background-color:#000000;
}
```

```html
<div id="change" class="fill">
  <h4 class="fill-div" id="message" >Hello world! </h4>
</div>

<br><br>

<select name="bgcolor" id="bgcolor" onchange="fillDiv()">
    <option class="1" value=1>Green</option>
    <option class="2" value=2>Red</option>
    <option class="3" value=3>Blue</option>
</select>


<br>
```